# Property myMethod never defined on myModel

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Following closure compiler instructions as outlined in [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export), I have

```
/**
 * ctor
 * @constructor
*/
function myModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.myMethod= function(a,b,c) {...}
    ...
}

window['myModel'] = myModel;
myModel['myMethod'] = myModel.myMethod;
```

the closure compiler completes with zero errors and compiled code ends with snippet like this:

```
window.myModel=b;b.myMethod=b.B;
```

but I get following warning:

```
WARNING - Property myMethod never defined on myModel
myModel['myMethod'] = myModel.myMethod;
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Clearly I missed something, but I couldn't figure what. Why the warning? how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are defining the `myMethod` property on an instance of `myModel`.

```
(new MyModel()).myMethod; // this exists
MyModel.myMethod; // this does not exist
```

To export an instance method, use the `prototype` to access it.

```
myModel.prototype['myMethod'] = myModel.prototype.myMethod;
```